# Element extraction returning null

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm trying out Linq-to-XML in an effort to shorten my code and make it more readable, but I'm running into an error where I keep getting a null. I'm trying to make the following code work:

```
var listOfFoos = new List<FooItem>();
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(fooData);
var fooNodes = xdoc.Descendants("Foo");
var foos = fooNodes.Select(f => new FooItem()
            {
                x = f.Element("X").Value,
                y = float.Parse(f.Element("Y").Value),
                z = int.Parse(f.Element("Z").Value)
            });
foreach(var foo in foos)
{
    listOfFoos.Add(foo);
}
```

But when I try to use `foos` or open the Results View in VS, I get a null error or "Object is not set to reference". Backing up from Linq-to-XML, I wrote the following code that works perfectly fine:

```
var listOfFoos = new List<FooItem>();
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(fooData);
var foos = xdoc.Descendants("Foo").ToList();
foreach (var f in foos)
{
     var foo = new FooItem();
     foo.x = f.Element("X").Value;
     foo.y = float.Parse(f.Element("Y").Value);
     foo.z = int.Parse(f.Element("Z").Value);
     listOfFoos.Add(s);
}
```

So what is it that prevents the Linq-to-XML from working whereas my second implementation goes off without a hitch?

The XML looks like this:

```
<Foos>
    <Foo>
        <X>AFE3-JJ-WO2N-353E</X>
        <Y>3341.3426661</Y>
        <Z>10</Z>
    </Foo>
    <Foo>
        <X>30IE-N2-IIS2-WER4</X>
        <Y>154.558921</Y>
        <Z>5</Z>
    </Foo>
    ...
</Foos>
```

This is the `FooItem` class:

```
public class FooItem
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }
}
```

And the stack trace I get of the error:

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of the object."
   at SigCaptureWeb.Controllers.HomeController.<RetrievePDF>b__1(XElement f) in c:\Users\ams\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SigCapture\SigCaptureWeb\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 101
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at SigCaptureWeb.Controllers.HomeController.RetrievePDF(String formCode, String dataXML) in c:\Users\ams\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SigCapture\SigCaptureWeb\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 108
```

Comment: how does XML look like?

Comment: Added it, sorry about forgetting to put it in.

Comment: Consider to post a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the error you get.

Comment: I don't think we can help without the actual code.  Your xml doesn't contain the floats and ints you're parsing, and your examples are using variables you haven't shown (i.e. `listOfFoos.Add(s)`

Comment: Changing the xml to add some valid values, that code works fine for me.

Comment: Assuming `FooItem` is a class with simple properties without anything funky going on, that is.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, it's just a container with `int`, `string`, and `float` properties.

Comment: Please post `FooItem` anyway + the stack trace from that exception.

Comment: @Chris Posted the `FooItem` code and stack trace.

Comment: Had to go away there for a while. Anyway, if some `Foo` in the xml is missing either A, B or C, you will get such an exception. That doesn't explain why your other alternative works though. Does line 101 correspond to the line with `fooNodes.Select`?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't find any issue in this code, please verify if any change need in this.

```
 string fooData = @"<Foos>
                     <Foo>
                       <X>AFE3-JJ-WO2N-353E</X>
                       <Y>3341.3426661</Y>
                       <Z>10</Z>
                     </Foo>
                     <Foo>
                      <X>30IE-N2-IIS2-WER4</X>
                      <Y>154.558921</Y>
                      <Z>5</Z>
                     </Foo>
                   </Foos>";
        var listOfFoos = new List<FooItem>();
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(fooData);
        var fooNodes = xdoc.Descendants("Foo");
        var foos = fooNodes.Select(f => new FooItem()
        {
            X = f.Element("X").Value,
            Y = float.Parse(f.Element("Y").Value),
            Z = int.Parse(f.Element("Z").Value)
        });
        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            listOfFoos.Add(foo);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

it clearly looks like you have wrong xml which might not have values in tags or wrong typed values , what you can do to handle/check what error is

```
 internal class FooItem  
    {
        public FooItem(XElement xElement)
        {
            float yvar = -1;
            int zvar = -1;
            if (xElement.Element("X") == null) X = "";
            else X = xElement.Element("X").Value;

            if (xElement.Element("Y") == null) Y = yvar;
            else
            {
                if (float.TryParse(xElement.Element("Y").Value, out yvar))
                    Y = yvar;
            }

            if (xElement.Element("Z") == null) Z = zvar;
            else
            {
                if (int.TryParse(xElement.Element("Z").Value, out zvar))
                    Z = zvar;
            }

        }

        public string X { get; set; }
        public float Y { get; set; }
        public int Z { get; set; }
    }
```

and then invoke constructor in your projection like this ..

```
  var foos = fooNodes.Select(f => new FooItem(f));
```

here constructor will ensure for sanity checks and put 0 or -1 if faulty values appears in XML.

Hope that helps !!!

Comment: If the XML is wrong, then why does the second code block work perfectly fine? It parses the XML elements without handling errors also, but I'm getting data back.

Comment: I performed null check & TryParse will take care of error handling , refer tryparse here... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx , you can look at result then and check where Y,Z is zero and that's where your code creates problem earlier

Comment: I don't think you're getting my point. I am not failing because I have faulty values in the XML. This is proven by the second code block. If there were faulty values XML that would throw errors on parse, then both code blocks would fail. However, the second code blocks works perfectly fine.

Comment: oh , ok , in your second block you wrote  listOfFoos.Add(s); at last where s is actually not there , is that a type ?